# Ptrace: Function Not Implemented in GDB Installed on Multiarch/Qemu-User-Static Arm64v8/Alpine Docker Container

Tags: docker, qemu, gdb, elf, ptrace

I want to debug an aarch64 ELF using GDB installed on an arm64v8/alpine docker on my x86_64 16.04 Ubuntu VirtualBox, which itself is installed on my Mac. In particular, to set up the docker I use the instructions [here](https://github.com/multiarch/qemu-user-static). That is:

`sudo docker run --rm --privileged multiarch/qemu-user-static --reset -p yes`

`sudo docker run --rm -it -v /directory_on_ubuntu:/directory_on_alpine arm64v8/alpine /bin/ash`

I install `GDB` on the alpine container and get the `PID` of the `ELF` process using the `ps aux` command in alpine, attach to it using `(gdb) attach PID` at point which I receive a `ptrace: Function not implemented` warning. I've read posts on `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` and `seccomp` tags but shouldn't the `privileged` tag in the first line take care of the security aspects of the docker? I also looked into the `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` file on both the container and my `Ubuntu` host and set the value to 0. It's also worth mentioning that I didn't find any `/etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf` file on the `alpine` container while on the `Ubuntu` host the variable `kernel.yama.ptrace_scope=0`. But I feel `ptrace` not being implemented means there is a bigger issue maybe with the way I set up the docker. Any help or workarounds for getting `GDB` to debug the binary is appreciated.

Comment: If I could make it work I'd write an answer but all I get is a SIGILL. So here's my comment: qemu-user is doing, in addition to cpu code emulation, abi system call translation. It just doesn't provide ptrace. Don't search for an other reason. Instead you can use qemu-user in gdbserver mode with its `-g` option. On it you can now connect a remote gdb-multiarch (no need to run it through qemu emulation itself).

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the comment. If I understand correctly you're saying multiarch/qemu-user-static containers don't have ptrace implemented? Also, while I've heard of gdb-multiarch and the target remote way of debugging using the `-g` flag in `qemu-aarch64` I'm really confused as is the server the host and the target the container? In other words, do I have to run gdb-multiarch on my Ubuntu machine while I run gdbserver on my alpine container?

Comment: As long as you manage to establish a tcp connection (using proxying, iptables' dnat with or without the help of Docker or any other way) it's fair game. You could possibly even run gdb-multiarch on the Mac as long as it connects in the end. But my attempts crashed qemu-user apparently after the sleep when running this on /bin/sh -c ... with a sleep; echo test in a loop, so I can't tell it will be easy.

Comment: @A.B I'll give it a try. In the meanwhile this seems interesting: https://qemu-devel.nongnu.narkive.com/3OHTvVB6/regarding-ptrace-implementation-in-qemu-user-mode. It seems after all that `ptrace` isn't really implemented in `qemu`!

Comment: here's a random example (most of the preparation isn't required, look at the end): https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8829/cross-debugging-for-arm-mips-elf-with-qemu-toolchain/8917#8917

Comment: @A.B Thank you for the link. I've gone through that a 100 times, though at the time I didn't know that there's a `multiarch/qemu-user-static` arm64v8/alpine docker available to run `aarch64` binaries built via `musl`.

Comment: That `ptrace` isn't implemented in `QEMU` user mode is confirmed here: http://people.redhat.com/pbonzini/qemu-test-doc/_build/html/topics/Linux-User-space-emulator.html

Comment: @A.B For some reason I didn't find any qemu-user package found on my Alpine Docker. Any workarounds?!

Comment: @A.B What if I run the binary on my alpine container and `gdbserver --attach IP:PORT binary_pid` and then try to connect to it on my Ubuntu using `gdb-multiarch binary` and then `(target remote IP:PORT)`?